# .htaccess removing *.php throws away the parameters of a URL that is passed as a GET parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

My request is quite simple. Using my current .htaccess conditions and rules as given here:

```
# Remove .php extension from URLS
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Redirect from *.php to URL without *.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]
```

Problem is, when I pass a URL that contains *.php?param1=A&param2=B as a parameter, it throws away "?param1=A&param2=B"

For example:
I want to redirect to: "/views/users/login.php?redirect=/views/home.php?id=1"
Resulting in: "/views/users/login?redirect=/views/home", which throws away "?id=1", so now I can not access that parameter.

How do I rewrite my rules so that it keeps those parameters?

Any suggestions are welcome and much appreciated.

**Update (2015-09-16):**

Removing

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/index\.php$ $1 [R=301,L,NC]
```

As it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use [urlencode](http://php.net/manual/de/function.urlencode.php) to encode the URL into a parameter.

So when building the link or redirect, use:

```
redirect('views/user/login.php?redirect=' . urlencode('/views/home.php?id=1'))
```

btw: redirecting to a "controller" in a folder called "views" might be a bit confusing in a few month :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you just need to add the query append marker like so:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\/index\.php$ $1 [QSA,R=301,L,NC]
```

that is "QSA"

Comment: sorry, this does not solve the issue. I removed that line anyway as it is irrelevant. I tried RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [R=301,NC,L, QSA], but does not work either.

Comment: my bad, that is:
^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [QSA,R=301,NC,L]

Comment: actualy the order does not mather I think it's the extra space that broke it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue (to some agree) using the following code:

```
# Enable rewrite mod.
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

# Redirect URLs that contain *.php to extensionless php URLs.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)\.php
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1 [R,L]

# Resolve *.php file for extensionless php URLs.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L,QSA]

# Resolve /views/* for URLs that do not contain views and needs it.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/applications/(.*)$ [OR]
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/home [OR]
...
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /views/$1

# Redirect URLs that contains /views/* to viewsless URLs.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.*)/views/(.*)
RewriteRule ^views(.*)$ $1 [R,L]
```

Comment: HOWEVER, I still run into a problem where http://www.example.com/users/login?param=someurl.php does not resolve, because of the last .php part. Any ideas? (PS. thank you @tripleb, mgrueter for your help thus far)

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST on redirects, otherwise POST parameters are lost.